# How to export thousands of Azure AD groups including all its attributes in a csv file

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I need to export lots of Azure AD groups into a csv file. It includes all the properties of the groups. I have thousands of groups, and when I use the cmdlet: `get-azureadgroup` the attribute `proxyaddresses` shows the information as below:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Here's the complete cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | export-csv C:/exportmetest.csv
```

How do I make sure the `proxyaddresses` attributes are showing the actual SMTP addresses? Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks and have a great day!

Here's the complete cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | export-csv C:/exportmetest.csv

Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | export-csv C:/exportmetest.csv
```

I need to output the correct `proxyaddresses` information into the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Below is one of the way to accomplish your requirement. Hope this helps! Cheers!

```
$GetAllAzureADGroups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$ObjectProperties = @()
foreach ($GetAAzureADGroup in $GetAllAzureADGroups)
{
    $ObjectProperties += New-Object PsObject -property @{
    'DisplayName' = $GetAAzureADGroup.DisplayName
    'MailNickName' = $GetAAzureADGroup.MailNickName
    'Mail' = $GetAAzureADGroup.Mail
    'MailEnabled' = $GetAAzureADGroup.MailEnabled
    'ProxyAdresses' = [string]$GetAAzureADGroup.ProxyAddresses
    'ObjectId' = $GetAAzureADGroup.ObjectId
    'ObjectType' = $GetAAzureADGroup.ObjectType
    'Description' = $GetAAzureADGroup.Description
    'DeletionTimestamp' = $GetAAzureADGroup.DeletionTimestamp
    'DirSyncEnabled' = $GetAAzureADGroup.DirSyncEnabled
    'LastDirSyncTime' = $GetAAzureADGroup.LastDirSyncTime
    'OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier' = $GetAAzureADGroup.OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier
    'SecurityEnabled' = $GetAAzureADGroup.SecurityEnabled
    'ProvisioningErrors' = [string]$GetAAzureADGroup.ProvisioningErrors
    }
}
$ObjectProperties | Export-Csv .\exportmetest.csv -NoType
```

Comment: If it concerns "***thousands** of Azure AD groups*", you should correctly use the pipeline and ***not*** assign the results to an variable (this will build up everything in memory before writing it). In other words: it is better to remove the `$ObjectProperties = @()`, `$ObjectProperties +=` and the `$ObjectProperties` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

If it concerns "***thousands*** of Azure AD groups", you might want to correctly use the pipeline to better utilize the memory (an possibly improve performance). For this, you should **not** assign the results to a variable:

```
Get-AzureADGroup -All $True | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'DisplayName' = $_.DisplayName
        'MailNickName' = $_.MailNickName
        'Mail' = $_.Mail
        ...
    }
} | Export-Csv .\exportmetest.csv -NoType
```